# Pandas group by a column and then filter it when all rows of other column value are same (eg all rows ="yes")

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Problem statement: I have a dataframe that I want to groupby with a specific column (my example col "Name") and then filter it further with the other columns all the rows value = "yes"

[image: pandas_dataframe]

expected output as below
[image: expected_output]

Answer (score 1):

You can try groupby and filter by the `No` count or existence in all desired columns

```py
out = df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda g: g[['col1', 'col2']].eq('No').sum().sum() == 0)

# or

out = df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda g: ~g[['col1', 'col2']].eq('No').any().any())

# or

out = df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda g: 'No' not in g[['col1', 'col2']].values)
```

You can also check by `Yes`

```py
out = df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda g: g[['col1', 'col2']].eq('Yes').all().all())
```

```
print(out)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the super-fast response - I thought I finished 99% of my entire code and this last part will be just 1% ...but spent hours and kept getting various errors....thanks again!